# Problem with a simple if statement in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make an if statement that will replace text in a google doc based on information from a google sheet. For some reason, it will always execute the first if statement, even when the condition is false. There's probably some obvious issue I'm overlooking, but I can't figure it out.

```
if(court = 'Emery District'){
body.replaceText('{{Court}}', 'IN THE SEVENTH JUDICIAL DISTRICT COURT IN AND FOR EMERY COUNTY, STATE OF UTAH'); 
}
if(court = 'Carbon District') {
body.replaceText('{{Court}}', 'IN THE SEVENTH JUDICIAL DISTRICT COURT IN AND FOR CARBON COUNTY, STATE OF UTAH');
}
```

I'm very new to coding. I'm just trying to make a script to help with productivity.

Comment: I would recommend always using the JavaScript _strict_ equality operators (`===` and `!==`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons). The creator of JavaScript referred to `==` and `!=` as the "_evil twins_" of the strict operators, probably not entirely tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare 2 values in Apps script (JavaScript) you'll need to use `==`

Here's a little rundown of the differences

- `foo = bar` - now the variable foo contains bar
- `foo == bar` - this is a check if the content of foo is equal to bar's content
- `foo === bar` - this not only checks if the content is the same, but also the type of the variable is the same

A little more practical:

```js
let foo = 10;
let bar = 5;
let bazz = '5';

console.log(`foo: ${foo}`);
console.log(`bar: ${bar}`);

foo = bar;

console.log(`foo is now the exact same as bar: ${foo}`);
console.log(`bar is still the same: ${bar}`);

if(bar == bazz) { 
  console.log('Because the content of bar (the number 5) and bazz (a string that contains 5) are the same this statement is true');
}

if(bar === bazz) {
  console.log('Because the content types of bar and bazz are not the same (bar being a number and bazz being a string) this statement is false')
}

if (foo === bar) {
  console.log('Because we just assigned foo the exact same value as bar, including the data type, this statement is true')
}
```

**Now for the actual answer to the question**

If the issue really only is the if statements, this should work

```
if(court == 'Emery District'){
body.replaceText('{{Court}}', 'IN THE SEVENTH JUDICIAL DISTRICT COURT IN AND FOR EMERY COUNTY, STATE OF UTAH'); 
}
if(court == 'Carbon District') {
body.replaceText('{{Court}}', 'IN THE SEVENTH JUDICIAL DISTRICT COURT IN AND FOR CARBON COUNTY, STATE OF UTAH');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `==` instead `=`

```
if(court == 'Emery District'){
body.replaceText('{{Court}}', 'IN THE SEVENTH JUDICIAL DISTRICT COURT IN AND FOR EMERY COUNTY, STATE OF UTAH'); 
}
if(court == 'Carbon District') {
body.replaceText('{{Court}}', 'IN THE SEVENTH JUDICIAL DISTRICT COURT IN AND FOR CARBON COUNTY, STATE OF UTAH');
}
```